# How do I solve This Error? 'Unable connect '

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

It's selenium. and the development environment pycharm
What does the yellow line in import os mean? and Hod do I solve This error??
And I want to save images crawled by Google using Selenium to my desktop file.
desktop file name 'Image'.
file address is '/Users/jun/Desktop/PyCham/selenium image folder

help me . I'm english pool sorry.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention from where to import the os.
Similarly to

```py
from selenium import webdriver
```

You have to mention from where `os` will be imported.
BTW, also, `path` need to contain the `hromedriver` with the extension.
Like this:

```py
path = 'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

`import os` is highlighted because before it you have an infinite loop. This code

```
while True:
    browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(1)
```

will never end because there are no conditions to stop this while loop and no breaks implemented.
So all the code under this `while` is unreachable, including the `import os`
Also I see that the path to the folder is too long and it looks like you pasted it two times. Since you are using MacOS (according to the file system structure), the path should start with `/Users/`